# Remove last element from array

Tags: vb.net

How to remove the last element from an array in VB.NET. I need to split the street and housenumber.

STREET

1. Split the address on spaces
2. Remove last element (missing in the code)
3. Join array

NUMBER

1. Split the address on spaces
2. get last element

My code:

```
'split address
Dim addressArray() As String = args.Content.Split(" ")

'remove last element and return the joined array
Return String.Join(" ", addressArray.Remove(addressArray.Length() - 1))
```

Answer (score 7):

```
    Dim foo() As String = "This is a test".Split(New Char() {" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Array.Resize(foo, foo.Length - 1)
    Dim s As String = String.Join(" ", foo)
```

or use lists

```
    Dim foo As New List(Of String)
    foo.AddRange("This is a test".Split(New Char() {" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    foo.RemoveAt(foo.Count - 1)
    Dim s As String = String.Join(" ", foo)
```

As far as using LINQ and performance, judge for yourself

```
Public Class Form1

    'to LINQ or not to LINQ
    'judge for yourself

    Dim stpw As New Stopwatch

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, _
                              e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim ipsumA() As String = New String() {"Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", _
                                               "amet", "consectetur", "adipisicing", _
                                               "elit", "sed", "do", "eiusmod", _
                                               "tempor", "incididunt", "ut", "labore", _
                                               "et", "dolore", "magna", "aliqua", "Ut", _
                                               "enim", "ad", "minim", "veniam", "quis", _
                                               "nostrud", "exercitation", "ullamco", _
                                               "laboris", "nisi", "ut", "aliquip", "ex", _
                                               "ea", "commodo", "consequat", "Duis", "aute", _
                                               "irure", "dolor", "in", "reprehenderit", "in", _
                                               "voluptate", "velit", "esse", "cillum", "dolore", _
                                               "eu", "fugiat", "nulla", "pariatur", "Excepteur", _
                                               "sint", "occaecat", "cupidatat", "non", "proident", _
                                               "sunt", "in", "culpa", "qui", "officia", "deserunt", _
                                               "mollit", "anim", "id", "est", "laborum"}

        Const tries As Integer = 100000
        Debug.WriteLine("")

        stpw.Reset()
        stpw.Start()
        For x As Integer = 1 To tries
            Dim s As String = arrayTake(ipsumA)
        Next
        stpw.Stop()
        Debug.WriteLine(stpw.ElapsedTicks.ToString)

        stpw.Reset()
        stpw.Start()
        For x As Integer = 1 To tries
            Dim s As String = arrayRsz(ipsumA)
        Next
        stpw.Stop()
        Debug.WriteLine(stpw.ElapsedTicks.ToString)

    End Sub

    Private Function arrayRsz(test As String()) As String
        Array.Resize(test, test.Length - 1)
        Return String.Join(" ", test)
    End Function

    Private Function arrayTake(test As String()) As String
        Return String.Join(" ", test.Take(test.Length - 1))
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't remove items from an array. The size of an array is decided when you create it, and can't be changed.

You can create a result that contains the items from the array except the last one:

```
Return String.Join(" ", addressArray.Take(addressArray.Length() - 1))
```

#### Edit:

If you are concerned about performance, you should not do any `Split` or `Join` at all, but simply get the parts of the string using simple string operations:

```
Dim pos As Integer = args.Content.LastIndexOf(" "C)
Dim street As String = args.Content.Substring(0, pos)
Dim number As String = args.Content.Substring(pos + 1)
```

This is at least ten times faster than any other method presented here.

#### Edit 2:

Here is the performance test code (C#):

```
Dim time As Performance = New Performance(1000000, 6)

Dim address As String = "aölskdjf öawe öofij 42"

Console.WriteLine(time.Take("SplitTakeJoin", Sub()
  Dim parts As String() = address.Split(" "c)
  Dim street As String = String.Join(" ", parts.Take(parts.Length - 1))
End Sub))
Console.WriteLine(time.Take("SplitResizeJoin", Sub()
  Dim parts As String() = address.Split(" "c)
  Array.Resize(parts, parts.Length - 1)
  Dim street As String = String.Join(" ", parts)
End Sub))
Console.WriteLine(time.Take("Substring", Sub()
  Dim street As String = address.Substring(0, address.LastIndexOf(" "c))
End Sub))
```

Output:

```
SplitTakeJoin 0,000511 ms.
SplitResizeJoin 0,000323 ms.
Substring 0,000031 ms.
```

using this performance test class:

```
Public Class Performance

  Private _iterations As Integer
  Private _displayDigits As Integer
  Private _emptyTime As TimeSpan

  Public Sub New(ByVal iterations As Integer, ByVal displayDigits As Integer)
    _iterations = iterations
    _displayDigits = displayDigits
    _emptyTime = TimeSpan.Zero
    _emptyTime = Take(Sub()
      End Sub)
  End Sub

  Private Function Take(ByVal action As Action) As TimeSpan
    Dim w As Stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew()
    For i As Integer = 0 To _iterations - 1 Step 10
      Action()
      Action()
      Action()
      Action()
      Action()
      Action()
      Action()
      Action()
      Action()
      Action()
    Next
    w.Stop()
    Return w.Elapsed - _emptyTime
  End Function

  Public Function Take(ByVal title As String, ByVal action As Action) As String
    Dim Time As TimeSpan = Take(action)
    Return title + " " + (Time.TotalMilliseconds / Convert.ToDouble(_iterations)).ToString("N" + _displayDigits.ToString()) + " ms."
  End Function

End Class
```

Comment: @dbasnett: You should read up on what `Array.Resize` actually does, and you will see that it actually doesn't resize the array, it creates a new array and copies part of the old array to it.

Comment: I know what it does.  The array, that I can reference, has a new size.  What goes on behind the scenes to accomplish this is not relevant, though it might have serious performance issues.

Comment: i'm working inside the program Visual Web Ripper. that is probably the reason i get the following error: unknown option unsafe: ignored take is not member of System.Array There is an option to load more assembly references but i've no clue which dll i should load then, if this solves the problem anyhow?

Comment: @Bas: You will need `Imports System.Linq` at the top of the file to use the extension method `Take`.

Comment: @dbasnett: You are mistaken. The array doesn't have a new size, you are referencing a new array that has a different size from the earlier one. What the `Array.Resize` method actually does is relevant just because it can cause serious performance issues.

Comment: As far as the program is concerned there is only one array.  I have conceded that there MIGHT be performance issues.  It seems funny that you would argue performance and suggest the use of LINQ.

Comment: @Guffa: And I suspect that the LINQ statement creates a copy of the array, though it might not strictly be an array, to perform its magic.

Comment: @dbasnett: No, as far as the program is concerned there are two different arrays. If you keep a copy of the reference to the original array, you will have references to two separate arrays, not two references to the same array. Why don't you simply admit that it's just not possible to resize an array?

Comment: @dbasnett: No, the `Take` method doesn't create a copy of the array, it reads from the existing array.

Comment: @Guffa - and where does it put that copy?

Comment: @dbasnett: What copy? The `Take` method *doesn't* create a copy of the array.

Comment: So what is it returning then?  The bottom line is that LINQ is a lot slower than the array resize.

Comment: @dbasnett: The `Take` method returns an enumerator. The bottom line is not at all about performance, because using `Split` and `Join` for this is killing the performance anyway.

Comment: At some point you end up with a new array.  Also, making it worse with Take is an improvement?  Is that what you are suggesting, that is is bad already so why not twice as bad?

Comment: @dbasnett: No, the `Take` method does **NOT** create a new array. It will **NOT** end up as an array, as the data is produced as needed. I suggest that you read up on how LINQ to Objects really work. Whether you use LINQ or not in this case should not be based on performance. If you are at all concerned with performance, you should not use `Split` and `Join` at all.

Comment: @Guffa - re-read what you have written.  You said "...just because it can cause serious performance issues. – Guffa".  Make up your mind.

Comment: @dbasnett: There is no conflict with what I have written before. If you don't use LINQ, it doesn't automatically mean that you have to use `Array.Resize`. You are really grasping at straws here, is it so hard to admit that you are wrong?

Comment: @Guffa - What was I wrong about?  Could you actually post code that proves any point that you made, other than changing the scenario?  I posted code that showed why not to use LINQ in this case.  If you can't then don't expect a response to further comments.

Comment: @dbasnett: The code that you posted doesn't show why you should not use LINQ, it only shows a moderate difference in execution time. I posted the performance test above, which shows that LINQ is about 60% slower than your suggestion, and simple string operations is about 900% faster.

Answer (score 5):

You could also try using [Redim Preserve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). These statements are carry overs from the Visual Basic 6.0 days and **are not** considered the .NET way of doing things, but it is another option. There may be performance issues though according to this [article](http://www.aspheute.com/english/20001025.asp).

```
Redim Preserve addressArray(addressArray.Length - 1)
```

Actually to delete the last item of array you would have to:

```
 Redim Preserve addressArray(addressArray.Length - 2)
```

since they are zero based and the length is one based.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `Redim Preserve addressArray(addressArray.Length - 2)`?

Answer (score 1):

This will return all but the last "word/number" in a String as an array of Strings.

```
Return args.content.Split(" ").Take((args.content.Split(" ").Count - 1)).ToArray()
```

Comment: i'm working inside the program Visual Web Ripper. that is probably the reason i get the following error:
unknown option unsafe: ignored
take is not member of System.Array

There is an option to load more assembly references but i've no clue which dll i should load then, if this solves the problem anyhow?

Comment: Import the System.Linq Namespace (System.Core.dll).