# LastIndexOf() method

Tags: c#

C# question:
I need to search backwards on a string using LastIndexOf()
The string in question is "South Dakota 1040"
Need to split the state name from the 1040 system indicator.
I can get the "1040" part of the string by itself, but can't get the state name by itself.
Have to go backwards since there are two spaces in the string.
Is there a better way to do this than what I'm looking at?

Comment: Yes, **regular expression**. Does your input string have a pattern, such as [state name][space][number]?

Comment: "but can't get the state name by itself" what do you mean? why not `myString.Substring(0, myString.LastIndexOf(' '))`?

Comment: Try this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945531/remove-last-element-from-array

Comment: Regular expressions are extreme overkill in this case.

Answer (score 6):

Use `LastIndexOf` to get the last space. Then split the string into two parts, you can do this using the `SubString` method.

```
str.SubString(0, str.LastIndexOf(' ')); //this gets you "South Dakota"
```

Be sure to handle when `LastIndexOf` returns -1.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to skin a cat in software development (note I have no ill feelings towards cats or any other type of animal) :) of these will work, I prefer the regex options if you have a specific pattern that you can pin down to, but that's just me  :)

```
// our string
string x = "South Dakota 1040";

x.Substring(0, x.LastIndexOf(' '));
// this basically does the same as above, but removes anything with a space and numbers
Regex.Replace(x, @"\s\d+", string.Empty);
// this is simmilar to regex above, though you have to watch out for no match cases
Regex.Match(x, @".*?(?=\s\d+)").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = "South Dakota 1040";

var state = test.Remove(test.LastIndexOf(" "));
```

Answer (score -1):

Without going codefreak here, the logic is to truncate your string in a foreach and concatenate strings found in the cell/list greater than the position [0]/[1]. Will this be sufficient for you?

Answer (score -1):

```
 string replaceContent = "1040";
 string content = "South Dakota 1040";
 string result = content.Replace(replaceContent, "").Trim();
```

Comment: The OP wasn't exactly clear, but I think the goal is to get rid of everything after the last space.